# reading data from Matlab into Java

Tags: java, matlab

I'm trying to read a matrix produced in Matlab into a 2D array in java.
I've been using [jmatio](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10759) so far for writing from java to a .mat file (successfully), but now can't manage to go the other way around. 
I've managed to import a matrix into an MLArray object using this code:

```
matfilereader = new MatFileReader("filename.mat");
MLArray j = matfilereader.getMLArray("dataname");
```

But other than getting its string representation I couldn't manage to access the data itself. I found no example for this or documentation on the library itself, and I actually wrote a function to parse the intire string into a double[][] array but that's only good if the matrix is smaller than 1000 items...

Would be grateful for any experience or tips, 
thanks,

Amir

Comment: Have you tried using MLDouble subclass instead of MLArray? Have you checked in MATLAB that the mat file were saved correctly?

Comment: How do you mean use MLDouble instead of MLArray? MatfileReader has just this API of returning variables as MLArrays. And regarding the file - yeah, iv'e tried several and they're all ok.

Comment: I meant to cast MLArray to MLDouble. Can you try `MLDouble j = (MLDouble)matfilereader.getMLArray("dataname");`?

Comment: Yes yuk that works! then you can access all cells by coordination and even have a built in function ".createArray". Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

[matfilereader.getMLArray](http://intra.csb.ethz.ch/javadoc/metabolic/com/jmatio/types/class-use/MLArray.html) has several subclasses to access different kinds of data in MLArray object.

To represent double array you can cast MLArray to MLDouble:

```
MLDouble j = (MLDouble)matfilereader.getMLArray("dataname");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that tool, but it's pretty old.  Try saving to an older version of `*.mat` file and see if your results change.  That is, add either the `'-v7.0'` or `'-v6'` flag when you save you r*.mat file.

Example code:

```
save filename var1 var2 -v7.0
```

or

```
save filename var1 var2 -v6
```

Comment: Iv'e tried that now, with the same results. But it's not an error I get or something related to the file, the problem is which code to use to get MLArray into java variables?